# Java: infinite while loop error

Tags: java

public static String checkStatus(String status)
    {
        while((status != "s" || status != "S" || status != "m" || status !=

```html
//this line is in the main program
marital = checkStatus(marital);

//this is a method that keep asking for s or m if user input is not s or m
public static String checkStatus(String status)
 {
  while(status != "s" || status != "S" || status != "m" || status != "M")
  {
   status = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter M or S for marital status: ");

  }
  return status;
 }
```

"M"))
        {
            status = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter M or S for marital status: ");

```
    }
    return status;
}
```

//I keep getting a infinite loop that ask for m or s

Comment: You also probably want `&&`.

Comment: please can you organize well the code